# How compute angle x?

Tags: geometry

I tried to find angle $x$ but i couldn't ?. enough assumption are given to solve this problem?
Notice::60(right) 70 (left )

[image]

Comment: are the degrees variables?

Comment: Sorry but your image is not clear :-( The angles are not clearly visible. It is better to draw by hand ...

Comment: Is it in Arabic. Top angle is $20$. Lower left is $70$ and Lower right is ?

Comment: @Nirbhay they are 60(right) 70 (left )

Comment: I think if you search "world hardest geometry problem on YouTube" this will come up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a famous problem if the small vertex is $20^\circ$ and the triangle is isosceles and the interior lines form $50^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ angles with the base.  Look up "serenditious angles."

I have seen about four solutions, all of which use pure constructive geometry and all of which are clever.  I have never seen a solution that is easy or even only moderately hard to discover.

**ADDED LATER**

I have also seen these called "adventitious" angles.